# Show multiple hidden divs with ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I have multiple divs which are generated with ng-repeat from a controller which loads content from api.

Controller:

```
app.controller('exampleController', [ '$http','$scope', function($http, $scope) {
   var tmp=this;
   tmp.data=[];
   $scope.collapsed=false;
   $http.get(url)...
}]);
```

html:

```
//ng-repeat limited to 1 for this example
<div class="someClass" ng-repeat="data in myCtrl.data | limitTo: 1">
   <div ng-model="collapsed" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed"> some div content </div>
   <div class="hidden" ng-show="collapsed"> some hidden div </div>
</div>
```

With example above I can show/hide single div on a click, but how would I show/hide multiple divs ? I want something like [this jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/hbshgh3j/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work

```
<div class="someClass" ng-repeat="data in myCtrl.data | limitTo: 1">
   <div ng-model="collapsed[$index]" ng-click="collapsed[$index]=!collapsed[$index]"> some div content </div>
   <div class="hidden" ng-show="collapsed[$index]"> some hidden div </div>
</div>
```